# How to call jQuery function onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this code to get the current url of the page in to div, when I click on submit button. I am not getting how to call function onclick. How to do this?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>localhost</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var url = $(location).attr('href');
                $('#spn_url').html('<strong>' + url + '</strong>');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="spn_url"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tadaaa! http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: I prefer `.on('click', function() { ... })` But maybe I'm being too picky

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/59/

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
var url = $(location).attr('href');
$('#spn_url').html('<strong>' + url + '</strong>');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

try this ..

## **HTML**

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
```

## **jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        var url = $(location).attr('href');
        $('#spn_url').html('<strong>' + url + '</strong>');
    });
});
```

Comment: **+1** `$(location).attr('href');` could be `location.href`, no need to pass to jQuery :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```html
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" onclick="myfunction()">
```

**jQuery:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function myfunction() 
 {
    var url = $(location).attr('href');
    $('#spn_url').html('<strong>' + url + '</strong>');
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    // this function will be raised when submit button is clicked.
    // perform submit operations here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> JS

```
 $(function () {
    var url = $(location).attr('href');
    $('#spn_url').html('<strong>' + url + '</strong>');
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        alert('button clicked');
    });
});
```

> html

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```